# Evaluate $\iint_R (y-x)\sin((y+x)^3)dydx$ on triangular region with change of variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

Evaluate

$$\iint_R (y-x)\sin((y+x)^3)dydx$$

where $R$ is the triangular region with vertices $(0, 0), (2, 2), (0, 4)$, by making a suitable change of variables.

What I have so far is that $u=y-x$ and $v=y+x$. From there I got $y=(u+v)/2$ and $x=(u-v)/2$.

Edit: I got the double integral as $\int_{0}^{4}\int_{v}^{0} u\sin(v^3)|-\frac{1}{2}|dudv$ = $\frac{1}{12}\left(-\cos \left(64\right)+1\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $u=\frac1{\sqrt2}(x+y)$ and $v=\frac1{\sqrt2}(y-x)$, which rotates the coordinates 45-degrees. The vertexes $(2,2)$ becomes $(2\sqrt2,0)$ and $(0,4)$ becomes $(2\sqrt2,2\sqrt2)$. As a result, the integral is,

$$\iint_R (y-x)\sin((y+x)^3)dydx$$
$$=\int_0^{2\sqrt2}\int_0^u \sqrt2 v\>\sin(2^{3/2}u^3) dvdu$$
$$=\frac1{2^{1/2}}\int_0^{2\sqrt2}u^2\sin(2^{3/2}u^3) du$$
$$=\frac1{12}\int_0^{2\sqrt2}d\left(-\cos(2^{3/2}u^3) \right)$$
$$=-\frac1{12}\cos(2^{3/2}u^3)\bigg|_0^{2\sqrt2}$$
$$= \frac1{12}(1-\cos 64)=\frac16\sin^2 32$$

Comment: How did you get those values for $u$ and $v$? I took mine from the given equation.

Comment: @TJKD615 - From the variable changes  $u=\frac1{\sqrt2}(x+y)$ and $v=\frac1{\sqrt2}(y-x)$.

Comment: sorry, I still don't understand how those values were calculated. Is my answer in the edit to my original question wrong?

Comment: @TJKD615 - The way you made the variable change requires Jacobian scaling.

Comment: You are correct, I forgot to add the Jacobian in my post and perhaps in my calculations as well, let me edit it and see. After making the edit, our answers match, my apologies, you are correct. I was using the Jacobian method as I was taught.